# Cutting dendrogram at certain point

Tags: clustering, graph-theory, dendrogram

I have a question about cutting dendrogram like that

It shows some hierarchy in the prison

[image]

I have to cut it to separate the group.

Is it possible to cut not all dendrograph at the same height like that:
[image]

or I have to do this this way:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about code to do this or do you want to know if that can be mathematically justified?

Comment: i want to know how it should be done manually

Comment: Are you talking about the R language? (if so, you may want some combination of options given in the dendextend R package. But it depends on which logic you wish to use for the decision. But the package does give functions to do it manually)

Comment: No, I don't want to implement it. I only want to know if dendrogram has to be cutting like in last picture or it can be cut like in second picture